# GCM send JSon message with special characters

Tags: c#, .net, json, google-cloud-messaging, encode

I am sending a GCM from my C# server using "application/json" (Downstream HTTP messages (JSON)). Everything works well, my Android devices receive the message.

But the problem is: If I send special characters like ä ë á é or similar then I get this error:

> WebException: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The
>   request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream
>   until all bytes are written.

I tried using:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("my méssägë hérë")
```

but then I receive the messages in Android in the wrong format.
Any help how to encode the strings correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing:

```
using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
{  oWriter.Write(msg);
}
```

with this:

```
Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; <-- important
Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream();
writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537219/error-httpwebrequest-bytes-to-be-written-to-the-stream-exceed-the-content-len)