# how to suppress or a way to handle file post web API error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am getting error while trying to `Post` stream to a web API method, the reason I understand that it may be thrown if the file being streamed is being written at the same time.

When file is not being written at the same time, then I am not getting this error.

`Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.`

I am trying to suppress it by using `ProtocolViolationException`, but still I am getting this error.

What could be the reason and how to suppress it or a way to handle it?

**Client Code**

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StreamContent(fileStream));
            }
```

**Server Code (Asp.Net Web API)**

```
try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await Request.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (ProtocolViolationException protocolViolationException)
            {
                //supress error
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

**Note -** While debug I found that for web API code, the 2nd catch block hit and the error message is `The client disconnected.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537219/error-httpwebrequest-bytes-to-be-written-to-the-stream-exceed-the-content-len

Comment: While debug I found that for web API code, the 2nd catch block hit and the error message is `The client disconnected.`

Comment: the default timeout is 2 mins is the file too big?

Comment: yes, file is too big

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I need to move `ProtocolViolationException` catch into client side rather than server side.

```
try
  {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StreamContent(fileStream));
        }
 }
 catch (ProtocolViolationException protocolViolationException)
        {
            //supress error
        }
```