# Amazon S3 upload error when updating to .NET8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0

I recently migrated our project to .NET8 and updated all the packages to latest version, but I keep getting a strange error when I try to upload a stream to Amazon S3 storage.

The packages list is:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="LEXolutionServiceBus" Version="1.6.55" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="7.3.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.3.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.23.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.23.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="OpenSearch.Client" Version="1.6.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.3.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="4.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.OpenSearch" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="STP.AspNetCore.StreamingExtensions" Version="3.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="STP.BlobStorage" Version="2.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="STP.UserManagement.Identity.TokenValidation" Version="6.0.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="STP.Extensions.System" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and the stack trace of the error is:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to write content to request stream; content would exceed Content-Length.
   at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsync>g__Core|27_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<CopyToAsync>g__WaitAsync|56_0(ValueTask copyTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpContentWriteStream stream, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentWithExpect100ContinueAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Task`1 allowExpect100ToContinueTask, HttpContentWriteStream stream, Timer expect100Timer, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.Internal.SimpleUploadCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at STP.BlobStorage.Aws.AwsS3Repo.UploadAsync(Stream sourceStream, String fullPath, String contentType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at STP.BlobStorage.Aws.AwsS3Repo.UploadAsync(Stream sourceStream, String fullPath, String contentType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at STP.IM.DocumentPoolService.Data.StorageManager.UploadContentStream(Guid tenantId, Guid id, String name, ITypedStream typedStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Projects\STP.IM.DocumentPool\STP.IM.DocumentPoolService\Data\StorageManager.cs:line 78
   at STP.IM.DocumentPoolService.Manager.DocumentManager.UploadDocument(Guid tenantId, IDocumentReference document, String name, ITypedStream stream) in C:\Projects\STP.IM.DocumentPool\STP.IM.DocumentPoolService\Manager\DocumentManager.cs:line 250
   at STP.IM.DocumentPoolService.Controller.DocumentController.UploadDocumentWithTenantId(Guid tenantId, Guid documentId, String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Projects\STP.IM.DocumentPool\STP.IM.DocumentPoolService\Controller\DocumentController.cs:line 389
   at lambda_method34(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

`STP.BlobStorage` is a package that I do not have code access.

Can anyone tell me what happen with this migration from .NET6 to .NET8

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:
The request is made "inside" and `AmazonS3Client` and the code that is used:

```cs
public async Task UploadAsync(Stream sourceStream, string fullPath, string contentType, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    Guard.ValidateFullPath(fullPath, "fullPath");
    try
    {
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
        await transferUtility.UploadAsync(sourceStream, _bucketName, fullPath, cancellationToken);
        _logger.LogDebug("Uploaded stream to {fullPath}", fullPath);
    }
    catch (AmazonServiceException ex3)
    {
        AmazonServiceException ex2 = ex3;
        _logger.LogError(ex2, "Got AmazonServiceException in UploadAsync while uploading object to '{fullPath}'.", fullPath);
        throw new StorageProviderException($"Got AmazonServiceException in {"UploadAsync"} while uploading object to '{fullPath}'.", ex2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex4)
    {
        Exception ex = ex4;
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Got exception in UploadAsync while uploading object to '{fullPath}'.", fullPath);
        throw new StorageException($"Got exception in {"UploadAsync"} while uploading object to '{fullPath}'.", ex);
    }
}
```

So I do not have actual "control" over the `Content-Length` when the request is made

Comment: See if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537219/error-httpwebrequest-bytes-to-be-written-to-the-stream-exceed-the-content-len

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error (HttpWebRequest): Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537219/error-httpwebrequest-bytes-to-be-written-to-the-stream-exceed-the-content-len)

Comment: I do not have access to the actual http request that is made, it is "inside" the `AmazonS3Client` and `TransferUtility`. The strange thing is that this happen when I switched to .net8 and updated all packages to last versions